# How to create multiple Multimap live views of an existing Collection using Guava

Tags: java, view, collections, guava, multimap

*I would like to create 3 separate Multimap live views of an existing Collection. Such that I have only one central collection to remove the objects from.*

This is supposed to:

1. Simplify the search of objects in a pool-like manner, based on properties of the object.
2. Provide a single central place where I can remove the objects from.

.

```
Multimap<String,Products> searchProductsByCategory=null;
Multimap<String,Products> searchProductsByType=null;
Multimap<String,Products> searchProductsByPlaces=null;

Collection<Products> productsAvailable=getAvailableProducts();

//Create indexed Views of the products
searchProductsByCategory = Multimaps.index(productsAvailable, productsToCategoryFunction);
searchProductsByType = Multimaps.index(productsAvailable, productsToTypeFunction);
searchProductsByPlaces = Multimaps.index(productsAvailable, productsToPlacesFunction);

//Get Customers from database
Collection<Customer> customers=getCustomersFromDatabase();

List<Product> productsReserved=new LinkedList();
for(Customer customer:customers){

    Collection<String> categoriesChosen=getCustomerCategories(customer);

    for(String category:categoriesChosen){

        Collection<Product> tempResult=searchProductsByCategory.get(category);

        if (tempResult.isEmpty()){
            productsAvailable.removeAll(tempResult);
            productsReserved.addAll(tempResult);
        }
    }
}

//Here continuation of functionality based on Types and Places....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Multimaps.index()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) does not return a *view*, and there are no view [implementations](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

You'd have to write one yourself where `get()` would just filter the original Collection. It's not terribly efficient, though, and if you don't need other methods than `get()`, you'd probably be better off creating a helper function.

```
public class LiveIndexMultimap<K, V> implements Multimap<K, V> {
    private final Collection<V> values;
    private final Function<? super V, K> keyFunction;

    public LiveIndexMultimap(Collection<V> values,
                             Function<? super V, K> keyFunction) {
        this.values = values;
        this.keyFunction = keyFunction;
    }

    public Collection<V> get(K key) {
        return FluentIterable.from(values)
                 .filter(Predicates.compose(Predicates.equalTo(key),
                         keyFunction)))
                 .toList(); // Copy needed if you want your example to work
    }

    // Other methods left as an exercice to the reader
}
```